# A doubt about the definition of base in Kelley's book

Tags: general-topology

John Kelley, in his book *General topoology*, defines a base for a topology as follows: a family $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in $\tau$, and for every point $x$ of the space and every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V \subset U$.

I feel like something about the empty set is missing from this definition. Indeed, most books define a base as follows: a family $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in $\tau$, and for every open set $U$ and for every point $x \in U$, there exists $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V \subset U$.

In the latter definition one is allowed to choose $U=\emptyset$. In the former definition this choice is problematic, since $x\in U$.

Anyway, I suspect that Kelley's definition should read as
$$
\forall x \forall U ((x\in U) \land (U\in\tau) \implies \exists V\in\mathcal{B}(x\in V\subset U)).
$$
In this case, could we choose $U=\emptyset$, forget $x$ and use $V=\emptyset$ to fulfill the request?

Comment: Kelley's definition you are reporting says "and every *neighborhood* of $x$", not "every *open* neighborhood of $x$", so your final formula is not a direct translation of it. However, both are clearly equivalent (i.e. Kelley's definition is equivalent to the one you say "most books" use). But you cannot "choose $U=\varnothing$ and forget $x$" like that. And you don't have to "use $V=\varnothing$": for $U=\varnothing,$ the implication is vacuously true.

Comment: In other words, your Kelley's definition
$$\forall x\forall U((x\in U) \land (U\in\mathcal V(x)) \implies \exists V\in\mathcal{B}(x\in V\subset U))\tag1$$
and your "most book"'s definition
$$\forall x\forall U((x\in U) \land (U\in\tau) \implies \exists V\in\mathcal{B}(x\in V\subset U))\tag2$$
are equivalent, and both allow $U=\varnothing$, for which the implication is true whatever $x.$
$(1)\implies(2)$ because every open subset containing $x$ is a neighborhood of $x.$
$(2)\implies(1)$ because every neighborhood of $x$ contains some open subset containing $x.$

Comment: My point is about the empty set, which belongs to any base in the most standard definition, since $U$ empty implies $V$ empty. If I pick the point $x$ first and then a neighborhood of $x$, I do not see why Kelley's definition implies that $\emptyset$ is in the base.

Comment: @AnneBauval in a sense the set $U$ in Kelley's book depends on $x$, and the family family of neighborhoods does not contain the empty set. But then $x\in V$ implies that $V$ is non-empty as well.

Comment: $U$ does not more depend on $x$ than the converse. And in the 2 equivalent definitions you presented, $\varnothing$ is *allowed* to be in the base (the implication is vacuously true for it, without having to reason about any $V$), but not obliged to.

Answer (score 1):

Let's set these definitions:

> A family $\mathcal{B}$ is a **Kelley-base** for a topology $\tau$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in $\tau$, and for every point $x$ of the space and every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V \subset U$.

> A family $\mathcal{B}$ is a **standard-base** for a topology $\tau$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in $\tau$, and for every open set $U$ and for every point $x \in U$, there exists $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V \subset U$.

All Kelley-bases are standard-bases: given an open set $U$ and point $x\in U$, $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, so pick $V\in \mathcal B$ with $x\in V\subset U$.

All standard-bases are Kelley-bases: given a point $x$ and neighborhood $U$ of $x$, pick an open set $V$ with $x\in V\subset U$. Then there exists $W\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in W\subset V\subset U$.

As for the empty set: one can prove that a subset of a topology is a base for the topology if and only if every open set is a union of basic open sets. Then note that $\emptyset$ is a collection of basic open sets and thus $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$ is open.

Comment: It turns out that my doubt stems from a tradition in my mathematical culture, which seems to prevent the logical implications of the empty set. In my studies of topology we never used $\emptyset$ in its full strength, and the empty set was added explicitly whenever it was needed. I see that Nagata, in hist book *Modern general topology*, seems to follow this habit: he states that a topological basis must contain the empty set in order to ensure that the empty set is open. He probably dislikes empty unions, maybe for pedagogical reasons.